# Power of matrix expansion

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

We know about the expansion $(a+b)^n\tag 1$,for scalar variables.

What will be the equivalent when we want to find

$(A+B)^n \tag 2 $,

when A and B are square matrices? Can we treat it as same as (1) expression?. Is there any equivalent expression for it?

Comment: Yes. You can think of applying C=A+B mapping to vector space on which A and B act upon repeatedly, whereas $(a+b)^n$ is repeatedly multiply 1 by (a+b) n times.

Comment: So you are saying $(A+B)^6={\color{red}1}A^6+{\color{red}6}A^5B+{\color{red}{15}}A^4B^2+{\color{red}{20}}A^3B^3+{\color{red}{15}}A^2B^4+{\color{red}{6}}AB^5+{\color{red}1}B^6$ ?

Comment: No. There will be ordering of products here.

Comment: Notice that two matrices may not commute. So $(A+B)^{2}$=$A^{2}+B^{2}+AB+BA$

Comment: So if it is commutative all is ok as per the answer by  Hamou

Comment: Hamou's statement is true if AB=BA commute as he stated. $AB\neq BA$. You have keep the ordering of the products. That is why you apply mapping n times rather than simply expand product like $(a+b)^{n}$

Comment: Hamou's link is not enabled.. Do you have the proof links sir?

Comment: You can do induction on n. I do not have the link. This is not hard for induction. I have done the n=2 case in the above. You can try to do n=3,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $AB=BA$ we have $(A+B)^n=\sum_{k=0}^nC_n^kA^kB^{n-k}$ for the proof see  [here](http://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2010/09/12/the-binomial-theorem-holds-in-any-commutative-ring/)

Comment: Sir Please enable proof link,it is not active thanks